# Save Data to database according to Date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image]

I want to post this event data to my database according to start time and EndsOn date and considering the repeated(daily, weekly, monthly) event value. let assume the start date is 2020/12/01 and ends on a date is 2020/12/31 and repeat event is weekly. So I want to save this event 4 times changing only the start and end times. (other fields remain the same). How do I suppose to do that?

```
 public Match addEventData(Match match) {       
      Match matches = eventRepository.save(match);        
      return matches;
  }
```

this is my save method in the service layer.

Comment: What's the issue? How have you defined the start and end dates in your `Match` class?

Comment: It's coming from the frontend. I want to call the save method according to start time, ends on, and Repeat event . How do I want to write the loop according to that data?

Comment: How are you sending that from the frontend? And again, how have you defined the start and end dates in your `Match` class? Just to note, front can send data in a format, but backend can modify that format to ease internal storage for databases.

Comment: This is the JSON` [{
"_id":"5fd97cdd1c506e6b11c27e10",
"startTime":"2020-10-01T14:00:00.226+00:00",
"endTime":"2020-10-01T19:00:00.226+00:00",
"location":"AVB",
"note":"note 2",
"type":"MATCH",
"teamId":"5fd97ce5432b53cb5610ac8d",
"opponentId":"5fd97ced52a48cab28b8a056",
"seasonId":"5fd97cf3af0899b520307e3b",
"tournamentId":"5fd97cf89a0ba1d5975a00d3",
"repeatEvent":"weekly",
"endsOn":"2020-11-01T19:00:00.226+00:00"
}]`